# How do I evaluate if my data represent the target variable before training a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset of points cloud where each point in the point cloud has a variable. I am trying to relate the local geometry features to that point variable by using [FPFH](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5152473), This means I am generating my own features from the dataset by first using an area of n-points to compute normal-vector estimations and from x normal vector estimations to compute the FPFH. However, the numbers x and n are arbitrary and other combinations might describe the target variable better.  So I wanted to know if there was a method to evaluate how good a given x and n value are at describing the target variable. I considered the correlation between the features (n,x) and the target variable but I read that this assumes [linear combination redundancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917979/why-do-we-use-correlation-coefficient-for-feature-selection). I am using scikit-learn.

So basically I have features X(x,n) and a target variable Y. **Which x and n, in the feature space X(x,n), describes the target variable, Y, best.**

I want to do it before the training because when I try to train it with my random forest regressor it takes 3-4 hours and I want to test for more combinations.

Comment: I found Spearman's rank correlation coefficient and will try to use that.

Comment: If the main problem is the time it takes to train a model, a simple solution is to train a simpler model which would be like a baseline. For example a single decision tree with a low max depth would be fast to train and give a decent baseline performance.